# GDrive api: Whenever the file name contains special utf-8 chars -> "Content size exceeds specified contentLength. [...]"

Tags: flutter, google-drive-api

I'm writing a flutter application, in which I want to sync files to Google Drive. However I came across the problem, that whenever I want to upload a file for which I specify the name with a utf-8 char. like e.g. in "Käsekuchen", I get the following exception:

"ClientException (Content size exceeds specified contentLength. 1410067 bytes written while expected 1410066. [--314159265358979323846--])":

When I change the name to something without the special character, it works fine. I guess the solution is quite simple but I couldn't find it.

```
import 'package:googleapis/drive/v3.dart' as ga;

var client = GoogleHttpClient(await googleSignInAccount.authHeaders);
var drive = ga.DriveApi(client);

ga.File fileToUpload = ga.File();
fileToUpload.parents = ["appDataFolder"];
fileToUpload.name = "Käsekuchen.jpg";

var response = await drive.files.create(
      fileToUpload,
      uploadMedia:
          ga.Media(uploadFile.openRead(), uploadFile.lengthSync()),
    );
```

So do I have to specify a certain encoding somewhere or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*The special character is endoded as two bytes. You need to account for this in the content length.*

#### Fix:

Change:

```dart
var response = await drive.files.create(
      fileToUpload,
      uploadMedia:
          ga.Media(uploadFile.openRead(), uploadFile.lengthSync()),
    );
```

to:

```dart
var response = await drive.files.create(
      fileToUpload,
      uploadMedia:
          ga.Media(uploadFile.openRead(), uploadFile.lengthSync() + 1),
    );
```

Comment: Thats what I thought and already tried. However I then get the error message that the content size is a certain amount of bytes below the specified content lenght.. So unfortunately this does not fix the problem